# How to get jQuery UI sortable work with absolute positioning?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to use jQuery UI sortable (http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) on a page to drag'n'drop sort a couple of DOM elements. All elements have absolute positioning and this is where the problems start. It seems that jQuery UI thinks that all of the li's are placed in the top left corner (that's where the placeholder ends up anyway).

I created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/winter/4ePe6/ where the problem is quite hands on.

What I want to achieve is the following: When item 1 is dropped between item 2 and 3, item 2 is moved to where item 1 was, item 1 takes item 2:s place and item 3 and up stays where they are. Before dropping the placeholder shows where item 1 will be placed when dropped, i.e. the actual moving of item 2 occurs before the dropping.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some more context of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: On my browser (Chrome), the items are positioned just fine. Dragging them and letting go reverts them to their original position. If you can elaborate more on 1) what you are seeing and 2) what you want to see, we might be able to help.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to reposition the items. If I drop Item 1 between Item 2 and 3 the new order should be Item 2 Item 1 Item 3. This works well if I remove all absolute positioning, but when I position the items it stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by skipping the absolute placements and worked it out with padding between the li's and an absolute positioned div-wrapper around the ul.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI might be making some assumptions, but the problem specifically with the placeholder is that its style is set for relative rather than absolute positioning. As there are no other relatively positioned elements, the placeholder ends up at the starting position.

To position the placeholder over where the moving element is, you need to do two things:

1. Give the placeholder its own class and
2. Set the placeholder’s position depending on the element that it’s standing in for.

For example for its class and style:

```
.my-placeholder {
  background:red;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  width: 10%;
}
```

Now all that remains is to set its “left” position according to the element that it is replacing. This is done by setting the “start” event handler to do that when the drag begins.

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    placeholder: "my-placeholder",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $(".my-placeholder").css("left", ui.originalPosition.left);
    },
});
```

Comment: I guess I was a bit vague when i posted my question. This gives me a placeholder where the item originally was, in all examples on sortable the placeholder moves when the item is dragged between other items. This works just fine as long as I don't set any positions on the li:s. Moving the placeholder as well as being able to drop items between eachother is what I'm trying to achieve.

Sorry for not being more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I CAN get it work...
But have to add $window.scrollTop() to item while dragging...

```
$tracksSortable = $tracks
    .sortable('destroy')
    .disableSelection()
    .sortable({
        update:function(){
        },
        sort: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.item).css({marginTop:$window.scrollTop()+'px'});
        },
        beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.item).css({marginTop:'0'});
        },
        items         : '.track',
        axis          : 'y',
        scroll        : true,
        containment   : 'body',
        placeholder   : 'trackPlaceHolder',
        distance      : 10,
        delay         : 500,
        revert        : false,
        cursorAt      : {top:15}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can achieve this. You can use some CSS trickery with the `nth-child` or `nth-type-of` selector to apply your absolute positioning to indices rather than directly to elements. Thus, when items shift around in the DOM tree due to how the sortable plugin works, they'll capture the correct position attributes since the indices will stay the same.

The other way is using the `sortchange` event of the plugin which fires whenever the order of the items in your list is changed. Thus, in the event function, you need to iterate through your items and re-apply the correct positioning.

See [this blogpost](http://www.nightcrawler.ro/2014/01/jquery-sortable-with-absolute-position.html) for more details on how to use both methods: